# Typed props when using Material UI makeStyles

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to migrate some of my React components to the new `makeStyles`/`useStyles` hook API from Material UI. If I understand correctly I can keep accepting `classes` as a prop from parent components as long as I pass the props to `useStyles`:

```js
const MyComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const { myProp } = props;
  const classes = useStyles(props);
```

I was wondering how to declare my `Props` type in that case. The equivalent with the HOC API being:

```js
const styles = createStyles({
  a: {},
  b: {}
});

interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  myProp: string;
}
```

Here is something that works but looks a bit verbose:

```js
const styles = createStyles({
  a: {},
  b: {}
});

interface Props extends StyledComponentProps<ClassKeyOfStyles<typeof styles>> {
  myProp: string;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);
```

Is there a better way? Ideally without the need for `createStyles` and using `makeStyles` inline with the styles declaration.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Did you find a better way to do this?

Comment: @rareyesdev unfortunately I'm still using my very verbose version

Answer (score 13):

To know at compile time which properties/classes were declared, I used such workaround.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Theme, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { BaseCSSProperties } from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';

interface StyleProps {
    root: BaseCSSProperties,
}

type PropsClasses = Record<keyof StyleProps, string>

let baseStyle: StyleProps = {
    root: {
        color: "red",
    },
};

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, StyleProps>(() => baseStyle as any);

const MyComponent = () => {
    const classes: PropsClasses = useStyles({} as StyleProps);
    return (<div className={classes.root}>This is root!</div>)
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Key moment here - do not forget to declare type for the **classes** constant.

You can reuse this types in other components and have all required information.

Answer (score 1):

Since TypeScript 2.8 you have the [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility type:

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles'

const myStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    margin: '0',
  },
  foo: {
    background: '#f1f1f1',
  },
  bar: {
    marginRight: '12px',
  },
})

type MyStylesType = ReturnType<typeof myStyles>

// use MyStylesType as type
```